# How to make Thunar show short file names?

Tags: xfce, thunar

By default, Thunar always shows full names for files, while Nautilus adds "..." to the end of the file, so they all look the same.

[image]

Can I somehow make Thunar behave like Nautilus?

Comment: What happens when you change files and folders to be viewed as a list (versus icon mode)? I searched around a bit for something to help you, but have no luck. You could always try posting to the developers listserv: https://mail.xfce.org/mailman/listinfo/thunar-dev

Comment: How does Nautilus behave?

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, It seems Thunar does't have this functionality yet *(I've exhaustively searched in Google and XFCE Documentation, there is no mentioning of this feature in official docs)*.

Thunar stores it's user configuration changes in `~/.config/Thunar/thunarrc` file. The options currently supported are [listed here](http://git.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/plain/docs/README.thunarrc). You can see, there is no settings for shortening file name. These are some [advanced settings](http://thunar.xfce.org/pwiki/documentation/advanced_settings) which neither support it.

I suggest you using nautilus. You can install it with `sudo apt-get install nautilus`.

Alternatively, You can request a feature in by going to [XFCE forum](http://forum.xfce.org/) to implement this or even you can help them by your coding skill, if you want.

For more information, see [thunar faq](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/faq) or visit [Official documentation for thunar](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/start).